JQuery Popup Reset
Sorry I'm pretty hopeless with Javascript. I have a script that shows a popup which then fades out. But I cannot get it to reset. The code as it stands only works once.


function myFunction$users5() {
  var pop = document.getElementById("myPopup$users5");
  pop.classList.add("show");


  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#myPopup$users5').fadeOut('fast', function() {

      pop.classList.remove("show");
    });
  }, 3000);
}
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction'.$users5.'()"><img src="unlovesm.png" style="float:right"><span class="popuptext" id="myPopup'.$users5.'">Login to Like.</span></div>



The popup shows and fades out correctly but thats it. Clicking the div again doesn't show the popup a second time.

EDIT: Changed to a one shot instead of a toggle.
I don't use jQuery, but it looks like you tell it to fade out your div, but never have it fade it back in again. One way of dealing with that is to use jQuery's fadeToggle() and match it up with the classList.toggle().


function myFunction$users5() {
  var pop = document.getElementById("myPopup$users5");
  pop.classList.add("show");
  $('#myPopup$users5').fadeIn()

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#myPopup$users5').fadeOut('fast', function() {
       pop.classList.remove("show");
    });
  }, 3000);
}
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction'.$users5.'()"><img src="unlovesm.png" style="float:right"><span class="popuptext" id="myPopup'.$users5.'">Login to Like.</span></div>




Thanks for your answer. I only want it to show onclick. Then fade out. Not toggle.

AL W, Right, I read it wrong. The problem is still as I said (your div is faded), just the solution is different. See my edited code.

Cheers. You got it 100%. I can't vote as I'm too new.
